# Python - Convert prefixes (kilo etc) to base number

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops

I have numbers which end in k meaning e^3. I have written a function to try and solve this problem:

```
def prefixFinder(in1, out1):

if in1.endswith('k'):
    in1 = in1[:-1]              # Remove k from the end
    out1 = float(in1) * 1000    # Multiply by 100

    print(out1)

    return out1                 # Return out1
```

When I call the function with x ( Want to replace the current value of x, `'10k'` with `10000.0`

```
x = '10k'

prefixFinder(x, x)

print(x)
```

The output I get is `'10k'`. But the `print(out1)` in the function is `10000.0` which is correct.

Im not sure what I have done wrong and anyhelp is greatly appreaciated

Comment: What if you assign `x = prefixFinder(x, x)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to give an input `(x='10k')` to make the function and after you need to return the result.

```
def prefixFinder(x):

    if x.endswith('k'):
        x = x[:-1]               
        return float(x) * 1000        

y = '10k'
y = prefixFinder(y)
print(y)
```

In this case the result will be:

> 10000.0

You can also assign the return to a variable:

```
def prefixFinder(x):

    if x.endswith('k'):
        x = x[:-1]
        out = float(x) * 1000               
        return  out     

y = '10k'
y = prefixFinder(y)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Out arguments like those in C or C# don't exist in Python, you have to return it:

```
def prefixFinder(i):

    if in1.endswith('k'):
        i = i[:-1]               # Remove k from the end
        return float(i) * 1000   # Multiply by 100
```

And then use it like so:

```
x = '10k'
x = prefixFinder(x)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `out1` param to your function. Just do:

```
def prefixFinder(in1):
    if in1.endswith('k'):
        in1 = in1[:-1]              # Remove k from the end
        out = float(in1) * 1000    # Multiply by 100
        print(out)
        return out 
x = "10k"
x = prefixFinder(x)
print(x)
```